# How do I get all of the customer which has a specific customer attribute value

Tags: magento-1, customer-attribute

I want a collection with all of the customer which has a specific customer attribute value. This is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter("my_customer_attribute_code", array('eq' => "prospect"));
        $collection = $collection->toArray();
        var_dump($collection);
```

The result of the var_dump is an empty array. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not load the collection. Unlike `foreach` and some methods that access collection data, `toArray` does **not** automatically trigger `load()` if the collection is not loaded yet.

So instead of

```
$collection = $collection->toArray();
var_dump($collection);
```

Use

```
$collection->load();
var_dump($collection->toArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific attribute value as added, for example `'firstname'` equal to `'some_name'`

```
$collection = mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('firstname', 'some_name')
   ->addAttributeToSort('email', 'ASC');

foreach ($collection as $user)
  { 
     var_dump($user->getData()); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You made little mistake in your code that include all eav attribute to `collection->addAttributeToSelect('my_customer_attribute_code');`

If my_customer_attribute_code is **customer EAV ** then you can filter this by function

```
addAttributeFilter('my_customer_attribute_code',array('eq' => "prospect"))
```

**1St: Need to load customer collection**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');
```

**2nd: then filter by** `addAttributeToFilter()`

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('my_customer_attribute_code',array('eq' => "prospect"))
```

**3rd: foreach loop to get get list of all customer having my_customer_attribute_code  prospect**.

For add an eav attribute to collection you need to use the function `addAttributeToSelect('my_customer_attribute_code')`

add

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('my_customer_attribute_code');
```

For getting all field use ->addAttributeToSelect('*') function which is include all eav attribute to collection

```
Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

If you want a collection to array then use below function ->__toArray () or ->toArray()

That means to get array of collection use below as exmpale

```
$collection->toArray();
```